# Applying Identity Theorem for holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, holomorphic-functions

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f : B(0; 1) \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $f(1/n) = z_n$ where
(a) $z_n = (-1)^n$
(b) $z_n = \frac{n+1}{n}$
(c) $z_n = 0$ if $n$ is even and $z_n = \frac1{n}$ if $n$ is odd.

For (a), I showed that function is not continuous at $0$ as $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(-1)^n$ does not exist, so function not holomorphic.

For (b), $f = g $ for infinitely many points of the sequence $1/n$, where $g(z)=1+z$ is holomorphic on $B$. So, by identity theorem, $f=g$ $\forall z$.

For (c), I am confused as if I apply Identity theorem for the sequence of even integers I get $f=z$, but that contradicts at, say $z=1/3$. Does that say there is no such function?

Did I give correct proofs of these questions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think all three of your arguments are all correct. One minor point: in part (b), the reason that $f (z)- g(z) = 0$ for all $z$ is that the level set $\{ z \in B(0;1) : f(z) - g(z) = 0 \}$ has a **limit point** in $B(0;1)$ (namely, $z = 0$ is a limit point of this level set, being the limit of the sequence $z_n = 1 / n$). Having said that, any infinite sequence in a bounded subset of $\mathbb C$ contains a limit point within this bounded subset, due to compactness, so what you wrote is correct provided that you're aware of this.

Comment: @KennyWong So this means I can apply it to any infinite sequence provided it is bounded?

Comment: Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function defined on an open set $\Omega$. Suppose there exists a closed, bounded set $K \subset \Omega$, and an infinite sequence $z_n \in K$ such that $f(z_n) = 0$ for all $n$. Since $K$ is compact, you can deduce that $z_n$ has some subsequence that converges to a limit inside $K$. Since $K \subset \Omega$, this limit point is also contained in $\Omega$. Thus we have shown that the set of zeroes of $f$ within $\Omega$ has a limit point in $\Omega$. So by the identity theorem, $f$ vanishes everywhere in $\Omega$. Sorry, that was a mouthful!

Comment: And in my first comment, change "bounded" to "closed and bounded". Sorry!

Comment: @KennyWong that's fine, I got the gist of it, you can edit if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasoning for part a) as well as part b) is correct as discussed in comments. For part c) use identity theorem for even $n$ and odd $n$ to get a contradiction(Like you observed, one way you will get it is equal to identity function and another way you will get that it is identically zero function.)